# bison - can't solve reduce-reduce conflict

Tags: bison, reduce-reduce-conflict

I tried some of the solutions I found here but it didn't work (could be that I applied them wrong though).
Here is some of my grammar:

```
Program: Marker1 PROGRAM DECLARATIONS STATEMENTS END    
;

DECLARATIONS:  DECLARATION SEMICOLON
             | DECLARATION SEMICOLON DECLARATIONS
;


DECLARATION: Marker2 VARIABLES_LIST COLON TYPE
;

STATEMENTS: STATEMENT Stmnt
;
Stmnt:  SEMICOLON STATEMENTS    
|   %empty
;
//More rules that include "STATEMENT" and "VARIABLES_LIST"
```

While `COLON`, `PROGRAM`, `SEMICOLON`, `END` are defined with `%token` (and are really just words).
I get the following warning:

```
Source.ypp: warning: 1 reduce/reduce conflict [-Wconflicts-rr]
```

I tried applying solutions from other threads but I couldn't make it compile, I understand what is causing it but I just can't figure out how to solve this.

Obviously precedence won't help here and I need to change my grammar, but how do I change it correctly without unfactoring all of my rules (I have a lot more rules than what I've shown here - http://pastebin.com/f308C4jN)?

**P.S: I'm not using YACC

Edit:
Here is the state with the conflict:

```
State 15

    4 DECLARATIONS: DECLARATION SEMICOLON .
    5             | DECLARATION SEMICOLON . DECLARATIONS

    ID        reduce using rule 4 (DECLARATIONS)
    ID        [reduce using rule 6 ($@1)]
    $default  reduce using rule 4 (DECLARATIONS)

    DECLARATIONS  go to state 32
    DECLARATION   go to state 6
    $@1           go to state 7
```

Here are rules 6 and 4:

```
4 DECLARATIONS: DECLARATION SEMICOLON
5             | DECLARATION SEMICOLON DECLARATIONS

6 $@1: %empty

7 DECLARATION: $@1 VARIABLES_LIST COLON TYPE
```

Comment: Please use standard naming conventions: UPPERCASE are terminals, lowercase are non-terminals (Or MixedCase if you insist.) Mixing styles like you do makes it painfully difficult to read your grammar.

Comment: Use bison's `-v` option to get a `.output` (suffix) file with the information about the generated states.  In there, you can see which specific states have the reduce/reduce conflict(s) and what rules are conflicting (and why), which you may then be able to use to figure out how to modify the grammar to remove the conflict.

Comment: @rici I know but I already wrote it like that. I can edit it if it matters.@Chris Dodd, I already did it and couldn't figure out how to fix it, so I'm asking for help. Should I edit the main post and add it there?

Comment: @user3765713: it's entirely up to you but if you are seeking free help, you might consider making the work of potential helpers easier.

Comment: @rici I edited and added the output. Could it be that the problem is because of the marker I've put on rule 7?

Comment: Yes. If both a declaration and a statement can start with ID and there is a nullable non-terminal at the beginning of one of those productions, then it is impossible to know what to do with only one lookahead token.

Comment: @rici: Yes that was the problem thank you very much, I will be more careful with y markers now haha. Thanks!

Comment: @rici and user3765713, it would be interesting that you transform your comments in a answer: It is always a difficult to guess that semantic actions (="markers") are going to be substituted by a new empty non-terminal...